How can I prove this fact of finite group representation theory?
The fact is the following:

If the group $G_0$ has a subgroup $G$ of half the order, then the
irreducible representations of $G_0$ always include a one-dimensional
representation given by a function which is invariant under all
transformations of the subgroup $G$ and changes sign under all the
remaining transformations of the group $G_0$.

I guess I should find such a function and show that the representation that generates is irreducible, but I dont know how to find it. Any help is valuable.

By a standard fact of group theory, since $[G_0:G]=2$, $G$ is normal in $G_0$. Now consider $G_0 \to G_0/G \cong \{\pm 1\} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{GL}_1(K)$, where $K$ is the base field of your representations. This satisfies all the properties you want.

May I ask you for a bit of development? Why does it satisfies all the properties? or at least, how do you see it so obviously?

$G$ is the kernel of $G_0 \to G_0/G$ and hence also the kernel of the composition. This means that it is invariant under $G$. If $g \in G_0 \setminus G$, then it gets mapped to $-1$, which is exactly the property of changing the sign.

Thank you so much. Sorry if it was very basic.

@olsrcra no need to apologize!
